# Spark Streaming - Kafka auto offset reset (Spark 2.4.5, kafka 0.8.2)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application (Spark 2.4.5, kafka 0.8.2) which I am currently performance testing with different message sizes.

```
def create_context():
    logger.info("Creating new context - not from checkpoint")
    print("Creating new context")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
    opts = {"metadata.broker.list": globals()['kafka_hosts'],
            "auto.offset.reset": "largest",
            "group.id": "test_v1"}
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic_listen], opts)
    kvs.checkpoint(120)
    print("Processing started")
    lines = kvs.map(lambda row: row[1])
    lines.foreachRDD(my_streaming_function)
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpoint)
    return ssc

ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpoint, lambda: create_context())
ssc.start()
```

The application starts, processing begins, but after some point (not being able to catch up with the messages) I get the following (expected) error on a certain batch:

```
Caused by: kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor33.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.handleFetchErr(KafkaRDD.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.fetchBatch(KafkaRDD.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaRDD$KafkaRDDIterator.getNext(KafkaRDD.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.foreach(NextIterator.scala:21)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRunner.scala:561)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRunner.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1945)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:195)
```

The problem is that the application never recovers from this state. After 'catching up' with all the batches (no active batches waiting), when I publish any new messages the error still persists, even though the message has just been produced seconds before processing it.

I'd have thought that the 'auto.offset.reset=largest' parameter resets the offsets automatically, but I guess that's only applicable for the start of the application. What options do I have for automatic recovery?

Comment: As far as I know there is no `largest` available for the consumer configuration `auto.offset.reset`. You can chose `earliest` or `latest`. When set to `earliest` it starts reading from beginning, when set to `latest` the Streaming job will wait for new incoming data.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, that's indeed true for the newer Kafka brokers. According to the old API's documentation, it seems that `smallest` and `largest` are the parameters. https://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html

Comment: Kafka < 0.10 support has been deprecated from Spark as of 2.4... Why are you not using Structured Streaming? Or https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Because the brokers I am working with are not supported by Structured Streaming (0.8.2)